# Get a mobile application set of icons

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, reddit

I would like to make a Reddit clone in Flutter ( just a personal private project), and I would like to get the icons that the mobile app uses. I tried to download an apk from pc and extract him but I found other images like the user default avatar, some animations, ecc.. but I have not found the Icons like the Home, Search, Notification and other icons. How can I pick them?

Comment: you'll have to just look them up and fine something similar... I don’t think theres any way you can have your hands on the assets they use.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio already has bunch of commonly used icons.
Steps to get the icon :

1. Right-click on `drawable` folder
2. Select new and the select vector asset
3. Click on clipart and search for the required icon
4. Choose your icon and set name and color
5. Finish

Step 1 :
[image: Step 1]

Step 2 :
[image: Step 2]

Step 3 :
[image: Step 3]

Step 4 :
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I asked. Flutter also has a lot of icons from Material Icon Theme, but I wanted a way to get the reddit's ones